# What does mean a TRect with exchanged (left,top) and (right,bottom) points?

Tags: delphi

I'm reading a 3-d party Delphi sources and stuck with a line, where Rect is initialized with another Rect's coordinates, but swapped, like this:

```
r, rsrc: TRect;
...
r := Rect(rsrc.right + 1, rsrc.bottom + 1, rsrc.left, rsrc.top);
```

`rsrc` is filled with proper on-screen coordinates, so (left,top) is always less than (right,bottom).

What does this mean? I can't find any mentions of possible purpose for this in the Delphi documentation.

Comment: Its hard to tell w/o knowing how `rsrc` was initialized and how `r` going to be used. My hypothesis: this can be of use in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183475(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything, just as `SomeVarName := 7` doesn't mean anything on it's own. Look further down into the code and see what the `r` is supposed to be used for; Also look for how `rsrc` was obtained.

It might simply be that the coordinates for `rsrc` were obtained using some math and it was determined that the resulting rectangle is up side down, hence the code rotates the rectangle to be top-side-up.

Answer (score 11):

Strictly speaking, a `TRect` is only a a collection of four integers. The meaning of these numbers depends entirely on the context. Most often, they specify a rectangle.

That is, it does not make sense at all to expect the Delphi documentation to say anything about the current issue! It is like seeing a car making a U-turn on a small road and asking, "Why doesn't the car's manual explain why someone would make a U-turn on this particular road?"